# Triceps involvement in bouldering

Tags: injury-prevention, triceps, arms, rock-climbing, bouldering

Is it quite common for the triceps to become weak from bouldering e.g. with a bicep / tricep muscle imbalance?

I've been getting some aches & pains in my tricep recently that I notice mostly after bouldering (sometimes during).

I used to have tricep tendonitis years ago which pretty much went away with the right exercises... but I feel it might be coming back and I feel like maybe its because my triceps have become weak / stretched from mostly bouldering and not really doing any tricep exercises.

Comment: As an aside, which exercises did you find helpful to get rid of tricep tendinitis? I've had the same problem while bouldering, particularly when doing steep overhangs with a lot of locking off.

Comment: @Alec It was mostly eccentric exercises, I've also had a PT tell me that my shoulder / scapular may be related too however. The scapular exercises also helped but can't ever seem to shift it altogether, especially if I'm going bouldering aswell as the gym

Comment: ...@Alec tonight I've been doing a load of thoracic mobility exercises and I feel like they may have helped, I think all the bouldering + corrective exercises with no stretching has probably caused everything to seize up. My back and the front of my shoulders feel like they badly needed it anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speaking entirely from experience, it's pretty common for me.
During bouldering, I find I use my triceps a lot for stability and mounting. It doesn't manifest as intense as my press day workout does, and it's highly variable on the routes I work, but there is a significant amount of work put on both sides of your arms.
I can't medically speak to whether tricep exercises would benefit you, or recommend a program, but I'd advise being careful with tendons. It could be good to go light on bouldering and try to build up strength in your tricep (and, as always, a trip to the doc or physical therapist will be you better than I ever could)

Comment: Thanks, do you mean that you run into the same problems if you don't keep your tricep strong?

Comment: I haven't myself, but I know at least one guy who has (unless that's you anonymously, in which case, hi). I do know that I used ti hurt my knee a lot while walking - turns out, I biked a whole lot and my quads could put out more force than my hamstrings, glutes, and hip muscles. Once I started mixing up my leg exercises, it got a lot better.